# Heroku não reconhece minha aplicação Django

Tags: python, django, deploy, heroku

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Django e criei uma aplicação denominada **core** dentro do projeto django de nome **django1**. Após terminado, resolvi fazer deploy do mesmo no Heroku com o seguinte passo a passo (com um repositório git ja iniciado):

```
heroku login
heroku create nome-do-app --buildpack heroku/python
heroku git:remote -a nome-do-app
heroku config:set ALLOWED_HOSTS=(link do projeto)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django1.settings.heroku
SECRET_KEY=blablabla
DEBUG=False
```

Tudo ocorreu normalmente e o projeto foi deployado, no entanto, o heroku simplesmente não consegue identificar a minha app **core** na lista de **INSTALLED_APPS** do meu projeto (mesmo ela estando la):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core', # tambem tentei o core.apps.CoreConfig
]
```

Percebi que o Heroku não estava reconhecendo pois no momento das migrações, enquanto o django reconhece todas as apps instaladas, o heroku reconhece apenas as que vem como padrão do django:

[image: Heroku não reconhece app "core"]

Já exclui a app do Heroku e tentei o mesmo processo algumas vezes, porém sempre acontece a mesma coisa: O heroku faz o deploy da aplicação porém não consegue "achar" a app **core** para realizar as migrações.

Segue alguns prints que podem ser relevantes:
(base.py é o settings.py padrão que o django gera. Com essa mudança, eu também já realizei as edições necessárias nos arquivos python asgi.py, wsgi.py, manage.py e o próprio base.py)

Estrutura do projeto:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Estrutura da app core:

[image: Estrutura da app core]

Arquivo heroku.py:

[image: Heroku.py]

Procfile:

```
release: python3 manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn django1.wsgi --preload --log-file -
```

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Em `INSTALLED_APPS` ao invés de usar `core`, use `nome_do_projeto.core`

Comment: @PauloMarques Acabei de tentar aqui, continua sem reconhecer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver.

O que explica a app do projeto estar sendo reconhecida localmente mas não no heroku é que, embora eu não tenha explicitado na pergunta, meu arquivo `.gitignore` estava configurado para ignorar todos os arquivos `__init__.py`. Por essa razão, resumidamente, o heroku "ignorava" os arquivos de migração da pasta `core/migrations`. Então, para resolver o problema, bastou eu excluir essa restrição do arquivo e o heroku reconheceu a app e executou as migrações normalmente.